# iOS Enterprise App Distribution "White Labeling"

Tags: ios, developer-program, enterprise

We have been making iOS apps and selling them directly to clients who then use their own AppStore to distribute to their internal employees after re-signing the app.

However, I just noticed the following note in the Enterprise Dev Agreement.

> Note: This Program is for internal use, custom applications that are
>   developed by You for Your specific business purposes and only for use
>   by Your employees and, in limited cases, by certain other parties as
>   set forth herein. If You want to distribute applications for iOS or
>   watchOS to third parties or obtain an application from a third party,
>   then You must use the App Store or B2B Program for distribution.

Does this mean we can no longer continue this practice or is "White Labeling" still allowed?

Comment: If you are selling it, then you are competing with Apple. If you are giving it away that is your choice. Tell me which client has they own AppStore?

Comment: The app comes as part of a complete system. Physical servers and a backend included. I can just say the app is free but you have to buy the rest of the system..

Comment: I am not a legal person, but would say that would work.